# Android, image loading and memory allocations

Tags: android, image, memory

I have an app that contains several custom views that extend View. Each custom view loads up a bunch of images (~20) and scales them down:

```
mBmp[img1] = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(context.getAssets().open("img01.png"));
mBmp[img2] = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(context.getAssets().open("img02.png"));
mBmp[img3] = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(context.getAssets().open("img03.png"));
        ...
mBmp[img20] = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(context.getAssets().open("img20.png"));
```

This is all within a try - catch block.

This part does not cause any problem. However, once I reach the point of scaling the images and I call my scale method which uses createScaledBitmap:

```
protected void scaleImages(float mWidth, float mHeight)
    {
        float mXRat = mWidth/1024;
        float mYRat = mHeight/600;

        for (int i = 0; i < mBmp.length; i++)
        {
            float oldX = mBmp[i].getWidth();
            float oldY = mBmp[i].getHeight();
            double newX = (mXRat * oldX);
            double newY = (mYRat * oldY);
            Bitmap newBmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mBmp[i], (int) newX, (int) newY, true);
            mBmp[i] = newBmp;
        }
    }
```

I get an error that I am trying to allocate too much memory.

```
01-25 10:16:44.227: ERROR/dalvikvm-heap(14548): 1497600-byte external allocation too large for this process.
01-25 10:16:44.227: ERROR/dalvikvm(14548): Out of memory: Heap Size=4871KB, Allocated=2544KB, Bitmap Size=18683KB
01-25 10:16:44.227: ERROR/GraphicsJNI(14548): VM won't let us allocate 1497600 bytes
```

No single image of mine should take this kind of memory when expanded into RAM, so why is it running out when trying to resize them?

Answer (score 0):

this is not single imagesize .this message is shown bcoz u r decoding it into bitmap and it is stored in heap for temp.so it is displaying tht msg.

Comment: Do you care to offer a possible solution?